# How to add ServletContextListener to existing @Service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-web

I have an existing class that I want to add the `ServletContextListener` interface:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    //...
}

@Component
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;
}
```

This runs fine.
But as soon as I add `public class MyService implements ServletContextListener`, then I'm getting the following error on `MyController`:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private service. No qualifying bean of type [MyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}.`

The application runs on a `Tomcat`. My goal is to `@Override public void contextDestroyed()` and clean up some resources inside this specific service on tomcat shutdown.

What is wrong here?

Comment: This seems to be an odd design to accomplish. What's your use case?

Comment: /edit above: I want to cleanup some resources on tomcat shutdown in `contextDestroyed()`.

Comment: There are Servlet container managed objects and then there are Spring managed objects. A `ServletContextListener` is a servlet container managed object. Though there are ways to combine the two, try not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to perform clean up tasks, then you should use `@PreDestroy` in a method in your bean:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @PreDestroy
    public void cleanUp() {
        //free resources...
    }
}
```

Spring application context will execute the clean up tasks before the bean is destroyed from the context.